# K-means Clustering used to organize Line Charts in R

Tags: r, k-means

I am trying to perform k-means to organize line charts. My first attempt was in Spotfire (as did in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HmQU_nWcoYM), but I don't know why, it doesn't work. Is there any way to do it in R?

I want to separate in clusters by their line profiles

```
                CTRL        PARK        NEUD
ILMN_1652003    8.127739459 7.416222105 7.207859527
ILMN_1652280    6.565974923 5.128247128 7.445328737
ILMN_1652580    5.315984723 6.155013137 7.829794002
ILMN_1652680    7.939345681 6.609423188 6.486453525
ILMN_1652790    7.793490858 6.867683625 6.70326419
ILMN_1653498    6.690623968 7.996630663 6.191421476
ILMN_1653652    7.070047041 6.055889722 9.410964986
ILMN_1653711    6.321439088 7.139000628 7.312927517
ILMN_1653934    5.96588931  5.299446928 8.488114668
ILMN_1654099    6.210458767 6.856590309 6.850658561
```

[example image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zcn9.png)

Comment: what does your data look like? if you have a way to save the slopes of each line, you could just say clust1 where slope > 0, clust2 where slope < 0

Comment: that won't work because I will work with three columns (three conditions), so I really need to separate based on the line profile.

Comment: running `kmeans(your_df[,c("CTRL","PARK","NEUD")],2)$cluster` will give you two clusters, but I'm not sure if that will give you the behavior you're wanting.